# I am having errors importing a table csv file into BigQuery

Tags: database, csv

First, I created a dataset. The next step is to upload the CSV file, but I encountered an error indicating that the file contains errors. I intend to upload it to BigQuery to learn SQL data cleaning. What steps can I take to address this issue?

Additionally, I need to clean the data using SQL. How can I proceed, considering that I can't create the table before starting the cleaning process?